# OnPush change detection not working with new reference in input of child component

Tags: angular

I have 2 nested components. One is a parent (**AppComponent**) and second is a child (**TooltipComponent**). Both components are using `OnPush` change detection. Now I want to update the child component view whenever it's input is changed from parent's code. I am passing a new reference to the child's input but it does not update the view.

I am able to update the child view by doing the following:

1. If I do not call the input change code in timer, button Click event triggers the child view update
2. If I call `detectchanges()` or `markforcheck()` manually on click then child view is updated.

As per the OnPush documentation, I should be able to update the child view simply by passing a new reference to its input variable. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <tooltip [input]="childInput"></tooltip>
    <button (click)="onClick()" >Trigger change detection</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class AppComponent implements OnChanges  {

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){  }

  childInput = {
    time: new Date()
  };

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('App component on changes.');
  }

  onClick() {  
    timer(1000).subscribe(sub => {       



      this.childInput = {
        time: new Date()
      };  

    });  
  }

}


import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange, SimpleChanges, Output, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip',
  template: `
    <h1>{{input.time}}</h1>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnChanges  {
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,)  {}

  @Input() input;

  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log('tooltip on changes called');
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` set in the `AppComponent`? There are no inputs there.Try removing it in that component. Leave it in the other. See if that helps.

Comment: Removing it from AppComponent makes it work. But I have similar scenario in my actual code where parent component has inputs. i did not put any inputs in sample code for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

@R.Richards is right - you should not have `OnPush` in the `AppComponent` because this is the root component of your app, change detection needs to start somewhere and `AppComponent` is where it happens. For your test to be more measurable, you should have `AppComponent`, `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` - all except `AppComponent` with `ChangeDetection` set to `OnPush`.

This code:

```
this.childInput = {
  time: new Date()
};
```

updates the `childInput` in the AppComponent class, but not in its template, so you never update the child component `@Input()`.

If you want to make it work you need to add one line after you updated the `childInput` in `AppComponent` class, so its template will get the new binding, which will then be passed to the child component.

```
this.childInput = {
  time: new Date()
};

this.cd.detectChanges()
```

Comment: As i mentioned, adding markforcheck() or detectchanges() make it work. And i have also tried it with 3 components, AppComponent, ParentComponent and ChildComponent. But still does not work by only changing the reference of Input.

Comment: That's what I am saying, if you change `childInput` in a component with `OnPush` set, it will change in the component class, but not in its template. So the template here `<tooltip [input]="childInput"></tooltip>` will still have the old value of `childInput` and will not trigger change detection in the child, because the input of the child is not changed. If you want the template to update, run `this.cd.detectChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really clarifying. Please update your example so `this.cd.detectChanges()` is called outside of the object :)

Comment: Thanks, done, code updated in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The change detection is not triggered, because only a value within your input object changed - not the object itself.

If you only have a simple property its better to use this directly as input (e.g. only the time not an object wrapping the time).

If you have an object and do need to only have a property changed, you can work with Object.assign({}, NEW_OBJ) where NEW_OBJ is your modified object with the new time set. This way you can ensure that the object reference changes and changeDetection is triggered.

Have a look [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#smarter-change-detection). Especially the part 'Understanding Mutability'.

**Update**

I made a Stackblitz for you to show, what I meant. You don't need to call the changeDetection itself, if you create a new object for your input.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-detection-on-push-example)

Comment: In the sample code, i am always creating a new object and setting it in Input variable of TooltipComponent. And i created the TooltipConponent with only one Input to make the example simple and clear. In actual scenario, i have multiple inputs in child component.

Comment: I made a stackblitz for you to demonstrate what I've meant: https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-detection-on-push-example

Comment: it seems that your example is working because of button's click event. Please try putting the code in some async call such as timer.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise you had a subscription in the first place. The thing with a subscription is, when using ChangeDetection.OnPush in combination with a subscription, the changeDetectorRef.markForCheck() needs to be triggered inside the subscription (after you change the value), otherwise the value within the component where the subscription takes place won't be updated in the first place and hence there is no valueChange within the child component as well.

Comment: Have a look here (section 2 and 3): https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4